# Temporarly disable mouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to temporarly disable mousedown event on all of my objects in my form. Got my timer up and running, tried disabling buttons, but I have other stuff, that can't be disabled. Any tips? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

:)